# indexPath Adjustment iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a `UITableView` that, under certain conditions, needs to have something added to the top of it. All data (except for what is inserted at the top of the `UITableView` under certain conditions) is brought in from an array.

Because everything is brought in from an array, I need to modify the indexPath that fetches those array objects each and every time the method `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is called. If I try to create a local variable and update the local version of indexPath.row, it tells me it is read only.

What would be the best way to implement this?

Drawing below (this is not intended to be code, but a drawing of the table view):

```
(REGULAR SITUATION) (3 lines)
array objectAtIndex:0;
-----
array objectAtIndex:1;
-----
array objectAtIndex:2;
```

etc. etc

```
(MODIFIED SITUATION) (4 lines)
blah blah modified insertion text here
-----
array objectAtIndex:0;
-----
array objectAtIndex:1;
-----
array objectAtIndex:2;
```

etc etc

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just add your new item at the start of your array?

```
// Create a mutable copy and add the item at index 0
NSMutableArray *mutable = [myData mutableCopy];
[mutable insertObject:newItem atIndex:0];

// Then store the new array and reload the table
[myData autorelease];
myData = mutable;
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Then you don't have to do anything funny at all with index paths :)

Comment: I didn't use this exact answer, but it gave me an idea for something else. The indexPath is still modified, but it's more of a hybrid using less code. If anyone needs details my contact information is in my profile.

Answer (score 1):

Don't go down that path. Just use the `tableHeaderView` property of `UITableView` to add something on top of the table. It will scroll just like a `UITableViewCell`.

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = aView;
```

To remove it, just set it to `nil`.

If you insist in this method, just keep a `BOOL` around to tell you in which state you are and if you need the extra line just subtract 1 from `indexPath.row`, like

```
[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1];
```

Answer (score 1):

[THIS](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html) is a great tutorial that addresses your issue.

Use

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

OR

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Return the String/View as something or empty depending on the condition that you use while deciding when to show it or not.